# Deploying Angular 2 app with express and mongo db on Digitalocean confusion

Tags: nginx

I have been fighting with deploying an Angular 7 app along with node, express, and mongo all morning and I'm confused out of my mind. Some how there are not good explanation of how to do this in the entire internet. Please help!

I'm on DigitalOcean. I have setup Nginx and I am able to see the Nginx index page at my IP address. I have also set up a server block with two locations inside of it, one for my actual Angular app and the other for my express api. Here is that code:

```
server {

        root /var/www/devgrub.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name devgrub.com www.devgrub.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/devgrub.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/devgrub.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.devgrub.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = devgrub.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name devgrub.com www.devgrub.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Inside `/var/www/devgrub.com/html` I have upload the code for my Angular app which was produced after running `ng build --prod`

Inside `/home/devgrub` I have my express / node app.

I can successfully get to my Angular app at devgrub.com, however when I went to devgrub.com/api is was giving me `hello world` which is from the original node app I made when following a setup tutorial for DigitalOcean. I restarted my node app which is running with `PM2` and now it says `502 Bad Gateway` when visiting devgrub.com/api.

I changed all my `localhost` api calls in my Angular app hoping that would do something but it didn't. I've created the DB with `use devgrub` but the Angular app seems to not be able to connect to it and since I'm so new to this I have idea where to even start troubleshooting. Please help!

**Update**
Here are some of the errors from the Nginx error logs

```
2019/03/16 17:55:10 [warn] 14358#14358: server name "devgrub.com/api" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/devgrub-api:8
2019/03/16 17:55:10 [warn] 14358#14358: server name "www.devgrub.com/api" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/devgrub-api:8
2019/03/16 17:55:10 [notice] 14358#14358: signal process started
2019/03/16 17:56:14 [crit] 14359#14359: *98 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D18C:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:version too low) while SSL handshaking, client: 184.105.139.70, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/03/16 17:57:11 [warn] 14436#14436: server name "devgrub.com/api" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/devgrub-api:8
2019/03/16 17:57:11 [warn] 14436#14436: server name "www.devgrub.com/api" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/devgrub-api:8
2019/03/16 17:57:11 [notice] 14436#14436: signal process started
2019/03/16 17:57:22 [error] 14437#14437: *100 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.175.29.181, server: devgrub.com, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api", host: "devgrub.com"
2019/03/16 17:57:51 [warn] 14501#14501: server name "devgrub.com/api" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/devgrub-api:8
2019/03/16 17:57:51 [warn] 14501#14501: server name "www.devgrub.com/api" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/devgrub-api:8
2019/03/16 17:57:51 [notice] 14501#14501: signal process started
2019/03/16 17:57:52 [error] 14502#14502: *104 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.175.29.181, server: devgrub.com, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api", host: "devgrub.com"
2019/03/16 17:57:53 [error] 14502#14502: *104 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.175.29.181, server: devgrub.com, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api", host: "devgrub.com"
2019/03/16 17:57:54 [error] 14502#14502: *104 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.175.29.181, server: devgrub.com, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api", host: "devgrub.com"
2019/03/16 18:05:21 [error] 14502#14502: *110 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.175.29.181, server: devgrub.com, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api", host: "devgrub.com"
```

Comment: The nginx configuration you have posted does not correspond to the error messages. Please post the relevant nginx configuration and _matching_ error messages. You also should read the errors, as it's pretty obvious what's going on in the ones you posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `502 Bad Gateway` it means you should investigate what is wrong with your backend. Is it really up and running? What do you see in logs of your backend?

Simple `curl http://localhost:8080` will make it clear.

Investigating your error logs, I could spot you have a problem in server_name directive:

```
server name "devgrub.com/api" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/devgrub-api:8
server name "www.devgrub.com/api" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/devgrub-api:8
```

I do not know which config you posted, but check your config `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/devgrub-api` - I guess you will see incorrect server_name.

So the solution to make it work - make sure your backend is properly working. If your node inside docker - make sure it exposes ports correctly, or both containers (nginx and node) inside one network. Checking logs of backend server is also a good point to start.

P.S. There are nothing to do with DigitalOcean, mongo or Angular2 app. I mean it is not necessary to add them to title, because your root problem is out of their scope.